# How to set a variable from an if statement with nested if statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone explain why the variable `a` is `nil`?

```rb
a = if true
    "domain" if true
    "nilr" if nil
end
```

but here a returns `"domain"`

```rb
a = if true
    "domain" if true
    "nilr" if nil
end

puts a.class
```

Comment: I just ran it, a is `nil` in both cases, what makes you think it is assigned "domain"?

Comment: _but here a returns "domain"_ – that's the same code with an additional `puts`. Ruby does not time travel. Printing `a.class` afterwards won't change the result of the `if` statement.  Double check the actual code you are running.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby evaluates each element of the block and returns, implicitly, the result of last statement to run. In this case it's the `if nil` test, which is going to fail, and hence, return `nil`.

Your code, simplified, looks to Ruby like:

```rb
a = begin
    "domain"
    nil
end
```

Where that block has a `nil` at the end, hence evaluates to `nil`.

If you want to branch:

```rb
a = if true
  if false
    "domain"
  elsif nil
    "nilr"
  end
end
```

Though this code is still pretty pointless since without an expression on your `if` that changes the result will always be the same.

What you might be intending is actually something like this:

```rb
a = case x
 when true
   "domain"
 when nil
  "nilr"
 end
```

Where `a` will take on different values depending on what `x` is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a value to check `domain` or `nilr` so when run

Step 1:

```
a = if true
    "domain" if true
end
=> result: a = "domain"
```

Step 2: `if nil` is runing

```
a = if true
    "domain" if true
    "nilr" if nil
end
=> result: a = "nilr"
```

Step 3: return a = "nilr"

Solution: You should use a other params EX: is_domain, env ...

```
a = is_domain? "domain" rescue "nilr"
```

Comment: What's with the catch-all `rescue`?

Comment: Isn't the ternary operator better suited on the last step?

Answer (score 0):

It does not return "domain". There is no return method in that line. The thing is, Ruby runs the last line and returns its results and for that if the last line is:

> "nilr" if nil

And the result of that line is nil, if it was:

> "nilr" if true

"a" would be "nilf".

You can check running that line alone and see the result.

To set a variable using an if statement you can do something like this:

```
a = if false
  "domain"
elsif true
  "nilr"
end
```